# How to get exception in init block kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, init

following the code, in `init` function I create a `Person` object，and have an exception，now I want to stop the progress in `catch` like java return. How can I do it?

```
class Person {
    val age: String = "10"
    private lateinit var person: Person

    init {
        try {
            person = get(2)
        } catch (exception: Throwable) {

        }
        println("----------------do it $person.age")
    }

    fun get(i: Int): Person {
        when (i) {
            1 -> {
                return Person()
            }
            else -> {
                throw MyException("aaaaaaaaa")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't `return` from a constructor in Java either.

Answer (score 3):

If an instance cannot be created due to errors in `init`, this error shouldn't be suppressed but delegated to the caller. So just do not catch the exception and the `init` "stopps" automatically.